# Odin: External monitor + incoming notification => x server down?

Tags: odin, monitors

I switched from Hera to Odin (I did contribute this time as this is a great job!) and I have a behavior that I didn't have in previous release.

I have a Dell Precision 5540 (native monitor 2160p) with an external monitor (1440p) and I close the lid to work using external monitor only.

In Odin, sometimes (a pain to debug sorry) when a notification is coming, the monitor goes to black. I move my mouse very quickly (maybe for nothing), the screen is displayed after a second or two and I can see the notification in an incorrect place (top left instead of top right).

It's pretty annoying... and a regression as it was not the case in previous Elementary release (same Nvidia drivers).

Thanks for any help,

Damien

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that can be resolved easily. You may want to [file a bug report](https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues) with the development team so that they can invest some time in fixing it 

Comment: Thanks @matigo, I think they can tell me what log I can provide to help debugging such strange issue...